# Syntax Error JavaScript Nested Object

Tags: javascript

Intent to create a js nested object is giving a syntax error. What could be causing the error?

```
window.thePosts = 
    {
    'ITEM1':
        {
            'SUB1' :
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
            },
            'SUB2' :
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
            }
        },
    'ITEM2':
        {
            'SUB1' :
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
            },
            'SUB2' :
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: `'SUB1' :` no opening bracket here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SUB* are arrays and should be denoted with `[]`:

```
window.thePosts = 
   {
    'ITEM1':
        {
            'SUB1' : [
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
            ],
            'SUB2' : [
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
            ]
        },
    'ITEM2':
        {
            'SUB1' : [
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MAKING MONEY','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
            ],
            'SUB2' : [
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                {'id:':'1','name': 'MARKETING','the_cont': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
            ]
        }
    };
```